# The content folder in my nuget package isn't adding the files to the root when installing the package

Tags: json, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-core, nuget-package

I am running .net core 1.1 and nuget 3.5.

Here is my nuspec:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>ClassLibrary1</id>
    <version>1.0.0.4</version>
    <title>Class Library Test Content</title>
    <authors>name</authors>
    <owners>name</owners>        
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>package to test config file transfer</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>TagUno TagDos</tags>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="appsettings.json" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\net462\classlibrary1.dll" target="lib\net462\classlibrary1.dll" />
    <file src="appsettings.json" target="content\net462\appsettings.json" />
  </files>

</package>
```

It produces this package:
[image]

As we can see, the appsettings.json file is located in the content folder in the nuget package.

However, when I install the package to my project, the appsettings.json file is not copied to the project root.

What am I missing? Or is this done differently in .net core?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `content` subdirectory is only used for `packages.config` projects.

Projects using the `PackageReference` style of NuGet references use the `contentFiles` section instead which allows to specify the build action to use. Those files aren't copied to the project, but are included as items in the project and optionally set to copy to the consuming project's build output:

```
<package>
  <metadata>
    ...
    <contentFiles>
        <files include="appsettings.json" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>...</files>
</package>
```

See the [`contentFiles` documentation for more detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#using-the-contentfiles-element-for-content-files).

Note that those files aren't copied to the project but included logically. Only `packages.config` projects support this since there was no other way to contribute files - the documentation also states that these files should have been considered immutable anyway.

Comment: This did not transfer the file to the project root successfully. I have updated my nuspec file to reflect the changes for review.

Comment: Copying the files to the project is not supported. it was a feature of the "old" nuget that has been replaced with content files.

Comment: Btw the practice of shipping "default configs" via nuget content files was considered a bad practice anyway and was discouraged. (content files should be immutable)

Comment: What do you mean by "included logically"?

Comment: it is automatically added to the msbuild project, not to the filesystem content of the project.

Comment: Is it the msbuild of the project that creates the package, or the msbuild for the project that consumes the package?

Comment: the project that consumes the package

Comment: I have the same kind of problem. I have a library that includes default appsettings. This default appsetting is properly packaged in my library. It is also properly visible at the path "contentFiles/any/any/appsettings.mydefaults.json" in my consuming project. Then, what path should I use when calling `AddJsonFile(path)`?  I tried something like `contentFiles/any/any/appsettings.mydefaults.json` but it threw an exception saying `The configuration file 'contentFiles/any/any/appsettings.mydefaults.json' was not found and is not optional.`