# Why is TinyIoC not picked up in my Xamarin.Android project when added using nuget?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget, tinyioc

So I installed `TinyIoC v1.3.0` using nuget in my Xamarin.Android project, its in the references, but I cannot type `using TinyIoC;` without a compile error. I would like to understand why this is?

PS. I know I can use the `TinyIoC.cs` file directly, but I thought it would be more convenient to update if I added using nuget.

[image]

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: This nuget package is not a real nuget package, and it did not contains the lib folder with the dll.So you cannot use its namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is related to the nuget package [TinyIoC 1.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TinyIoC/1.3.0) itself.

The nuget package does not contain the `lib` folder with the related `dll` so that you can not use the format by `using namespace`.

[image]

**Note: Important**

The nuget package contains a folder called **Content**. This folder will copy its content into the main project with [packages.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config) when you install the nuget pacakge.  [See this similar issue on so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44709212/the-content-folder-in-my-nuget-package-isnt-adding-the-files-to-the-root-when-i).

And it will make `TinyloC.cs` file directly in your main project and you can just modify it there.

I have created a net framework project with `packages.config` format.

[image]

**However**, since your project is xamarin andorid app, it uses [PackageReference nuget manage format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files), and **content** folder does not work for it. **Instead**, you should use **ContentFiles** folder, but this nuget package does not contain it.

**To make this issue more clearly, you should contact the author of the nuget package to report this problem.**