# UWP Install MVVM Light and NuGet

Tags: uwp, nuget, visual-studio-2019, mvvm-light

I am working on an UWP Project in Visual Studio 2019 and I wanted to install the MVVM package. The problem is that, as far as I am concerned, since NuGet 3.1 package installations do not allow to create new files and folders because they don't know what to do when those packages are uninstalled. I wanted to know how I could install MVVM Light so that creates these files and completes successfully the installation. Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your uwp project uses [PackageReference nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files). And the author of [MvvmLight nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/) has added **content** node under the **nupkg**.
It will add the files of the **content** folder from the **nupkg** into the main project automatically. However, this works only for [packages.config nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config).

[image]

**And** since your UWPprojects uses **PackageReference**, it will not work.

**Instead**, the author should add **contentFiles** node into the **nupkg** file. See [one document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files) ,[two document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64146987/why-is-tinyioc-not-picked-up-in-my-xamarin-android-project-when-added-using-nuge) and [three document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44709212/the-content-folder-in-my-nuget-package-isnt-adding-the-files-to-the-root-when-i).

**Suggestion**

**1)** You have to contact with the author of the nuget package to add **contentFiles** into the nuget package.

**2)** Since the solution one might take a long time, you could try to use `packages.config` nuget management format. Although it might have some issues, but it worth trying and it is the fast way to get what you want  And please make a backup of your project.

**a)** remember any nuget packages and its version you installed on the uwp project.

**b)** then, enter the `csproj` file of the uwp project

```
comment or delete these xml nodes:


  <PropertyGroup>
    <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And delete  all **PackageReference** node like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform">
      <Version>6.2.10</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
......
......
<ItemGroup>
```

**c)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder of the uwp project.

**d)** restart VS, enter `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`General` and change **Package Management** to `Packages.config`.

[image]

**e)** then install these nuget packages by `packages.config`.

Note: please first install `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` nuget package version `6.2.8`. After that, install the other nuget packages including `MvvmLight`.

**And** you will see the content files from the nuget package:

[image]